# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

So after looking through countless sources trying to find out what this truly means, I have found absolutely nothing useful.  Let's clear this up, I KNOW WHAT THE ERROR MEANS.  But I have no idea what is causing it.  My code is as follows:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView selector = this.itemListView;
    FeedItem item = selector.SelectedItem as FeedItem;
    if (item != null && this.Frame != null)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(WebViewPage), item.Title); //This line is the problem
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is navigate to a full webview page based on a selection from the itemListView.  I do this through using an AppBar button.  When I step through this code line by line, everything runs as intended until I attempt to navigate.  Immediately before the navigation, none of my objects are null (according to intellisense and the fact that the if statement is entered), and it remains this way after I step through the navigation.  The program doesn't fail, it just shows up as an exception in the Intellitrace box, and the navigation never occurs, leaving the user to click the appbar button as much as they please to no avail.

Webview page code (According to IntelliTrace, I never actually reach any code in this page).

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String,Object> pageState)
{
    FeedItem item = FeedUtilities.GetItemByTitle((string)navigationParameter);
    pageTitle.DataContext = item;

    itemContentWebView.Navigate(item.Link);
}
```

This has been frustrating me for a couple days now, so any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there a stacktrace? (you might need to add a `try`/`catch` to get it)

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a little bit?  I'm still a little new to this in some respects.

Comment: Perhaps you could highlight the line that this error is occurring on?

Comment: Added a comment after the navigation attempt

Comment: That's what I figured, but the exception isn't really helping me see what is wrong.  Even when I step into the function, it redirects somewhere else where I step through it and still, the exception isn't thrown until immediately following the attempted navigation.

Comment: What is `Frame`? What sort of control is it?

Comment: From what I understand, it is the current window, and by calling navigate, you are moving it to a different view (in this case the WebViewPage, the second argument is just a string that I pass to the new page).  Once again, I've only been programming in C# for 3-4 months now, so my understanding is somewhat rough around the edges.

Comment: please show WebViewPage code

Comment: Added above, but please note that the code never actually reaches that point according to intelliTrace.

Comment: Could you actually paste in the complete error message?

Comment: +  Thrown: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (System.NullReferenceException) Exception Message = "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", Exception Type = "System.NullReferenceException", Exception WinRT Data = ""

Comment: is it possible that Title property of item is null ? You check if item is null but what about title ?

Comment: It's a good suggestion, unfortunately, the title property has the appropriate value, as do all of item's other properties.

Comment: Is it possible your WebViewpage has a null in its initialization code? Do take a look at the WebViewPage's initialization sequence to see if any control or any particular object could possibly throw a runtime null exception. Maybe a missing resource or anything. Anything in the page that get's called before the LoadState.

Comment: All that is in WebViewPage is what you see above, and the call to this.InitializeComponent().

Comment: Put a try catch around InitializeComponent. See if it fails there. InitializeComponent is where the controls are initialized. It could cause an issue if any resources are unavailable or if any controls fail.

Comment: Yeah, no dice unfortunately, never reaches the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rootFrame = new Frame();
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SearchResultsPage1));

Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
Window.Current.Activate();
```